# Is there a react native package for adding generic passes to google wallet?

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, android-pay, react-native-native-module

I am searching for a react native package which add generic passes into google wallet. There are some old packages that handle .pkpass files. But it's not what i'm looking for. Could anyone help me on this?

I tried write a native module for it in kotlin, but i am not familiar with android native development.